# Why does Android force close apps after update?

Tags: updates, linux

I have been using Linux in my PC for a long time. I had noticed that if an app is updated while it is running, the app is not forced to close or restart. But in Android, I noticed that apps are forced to close after updating.
Android being based on Linux kernel, why does it force close an app after updating that app?

Comment: I assume this is a simple design decision Google made. An updated app that has still an old version running can have massive side effects if the app process is not aware of such situations. Therefore if the app installation process  starts the old process is ended. BTW: Linux or in detail Ubuntu with apt usually works the same to my experience (or at least for those services I recognize). If you update a service via apt it will be restarted.

Comment: In Android it's the operating system (activity manager) which takes care of app's life cycles (start, pause, resume, stop) and manages its resources when it's in background, in foreground, or when home button or back button is pressed, or when screen is locked / unlocked, or when app starts/stops a foreground/background service, and so on. AM keeps track of apps on per UID basis. In Linux distros, human user is the UID. And OS doesn't interfere with program starting or closing unless user asks to do so. So it's the entirely different userspace design, nothing to do with kernel.